# Designing view using table layout for Android tab?

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to design below view for the purpose to display it on Android Tablet. I want to know the xml code to design this kind of view. can anyone help me ?

[image]

I used following code now...
but how to set 50% tablelayout on both side

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:gravity="left" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1">
    <TableLayout android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/tableLayout2" android:id="@+id/tableLayout1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <TextView android:text="table 1"></TextView>


    </TableLayout>

     <TableLayout android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tableLayout1" android:id="@+id/tableLayout2" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="fill_parent">


    <TextView android:text="table 2"></TextView>



     </TableLayout> 

     </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside TableLayout use TableRow and use other views inside TableRow.

Comment: yes i'll add it. But how to make both Tablelayout 50 % width.

Comment: Give android:layout_weight="1" for each views in TableRow, I tried this it is working.

Comment: Here is the code I tried  <TableLayout
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content">
 <TableRow
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content">
 
  <TextView
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text="TextView1"
   android:layout_weight="1"/>
  <Button
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text="Button2"
   android:layout_weight="1"/>
 
 </TableRow>
 </TableLayout>

Comment: @Monu if it is helpful for you please vote up and mark the tick

Comment: I want to show two list view So i am using table layout for that and want to show that table layout of equal width..

Comment: You mean you have two TableLayout each one having a ListView? If it so give layout_weight for TableLayout

Comment: You just check again android:layout_weight is available for table layout

Answer (score 0):

I would use a 2 linear layouts inside a another linear layout.
The child layout will use layout_weight = 1.

Comment: I want to show two list view So i am using table layout for that and want to show that two table layout of equal width..